# Trying to put a chart from a Windows Form C# into PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, windows-forms-designer

Ok so I have gone ahead and done all my steps. My problem is now the export to pdf. I have gotten it to work using a screenshot and iTextSharp. However, my problem is that what if for some reason that screen is not the main screen when the it takes a screenshot it'll take a screenshot of something else and save that as the report. Is there a way to save directly the form or even go one step further and save certain parts of the form. I found this doing my search but I don't know what my next step would be:

```
public void SaveToPdf()
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("E:/a.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        document.Add(p);
        document.Add("DONT KNOW WHAT THE SYNTAX FOR CHART WOULD BE")
        document.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Save the Chart as an image, make it large enough and use a higher than screen dpi; then add image!

Comment: Are you referring to a screenshot? As I have tried that however, my goal is to have the program running in the background or minimized if this happens then the screenshot will be of something else.

Comment: What's your chart component?

Comment: No. You can call Save:[`Chart.SaveImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456181.aspx) method on MSChart.

Comment: Oh sorry yes you are right. I am going to try that and see if I can clear that folder after creating my pdf report as there are mutliple charts and then later on it should recreate them again in a new pdf. And @AliBahrami it is just a normal line graph chart pulling data from a mysql table

Comment: As @TaW mentioned, if you are using `MSChart` you can use SaveImage method.

Comment: Code example: `using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    chart1.Size = new Size(1500, 1500); //// use a suitable number!
    chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
    bmp.SetResolution(150, 150); // use a suitable number!
    // do stuff with the image; Dispose of it when done!
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}`

Comment: Any ideas why my graph shows a straight line from the first point to the last. Here is my code `MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select * from reporttesting ORDER BY Time DESC;", conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.InsertXY(0,myReader.GetDateTime("Time"), myReader.GetInt32("Temp"));
                }
            }`